# Bokeh: trigger callback update for multiple graphs

Tags: javascript, python, callback, bokeh

I have data with three dimensions x, y and z. I display them as a bokeh gridplot with three separate graphs below each other. The x-axes are linked so that if I pan in one of the graphs, the other ones are updated:

```
time = np.arange(len(data))

labels = ["x","y","z"]
plots = []

for i in range(3):
    if i != 0:
        fig = figure(plot_width=900, plot_height=150, x_range=first.x_range)
    else:
        fig = figure(plot_width=900, plot_height=150)
        # First figure is saved as other figures are linked to this one
        first = fig

    source = ColumnDataSource({'x': time, 'y': data[:,i]})
    fig.line('x','y', source=source)

    fig.yaxis.axis_label = labels[i]
    plots.append([fig])

p = gridplot(([plots[0], plots[1], plots[2]]))
show(p)
```

I also implemented a callback for the x-axes ranges which updates the graph each time the x-range changes so that the plot fills the complete graph on the y-axis:

```
fig.x_range.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, xrange=fig.x_range,
                                yrange=fig.y_range), code=adjust_y_range_js)
```

In this code, the range objects are set with the newly calculated ranges, which triggers an update in the graph from which the callback originated. I.e. if I zoom in on the first of the three graphs, the y-range of the first graph will be updated so that it fills the plot. Due to the link with the other plots, the x-ranges of the other two plots will change as well. However, their x_ranges won't trigger the callback. I tried passing the other ranges in the callback JS code and updating them in the following manner, but unsuccessfully:

```
xrange_other.trigger('change');
```

This will make the box selection tool freeze for some reason, i.e. it will permanently try to make a selection. Any ideas how to update the whole plot in another way?

The code for the callback is the following (taken from someone's github, but can't find the original source unfortunately):

```
adjust_y_range_js = """
function isNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

var data = source.get('data');
var start = yrange.get('start');
var end = yrange.get('end');

var time_start = xrange.get('start');
var time_end = xrange.get('end');

var pre_max_old = end;
var pre_min_old = start;

var time = data['x'];
var pre = data['y'];
t_idx_start = time.filter(function(st){return st>=time_start})[0];
t_idx_start = time.indexOf(t_idx_start);

t_idx_end = time.filter(function(st){return st>=time_end})[0];
t_idx_end = time.indexOf(t_idx_end);

var pre_interval = pre.slice(t_idx_start, t_idx_end);
pre_interval = pre_interval.filter(function(st){return !isNaN(st)});
var pre_max = Math.max.apply(null, pre_interval);
var pre_min = Math.min.apply(null, pre_interval);
var ten_percent = (pre_max-pre_min)*0.1;

pre_max = pre_max + ten_percent;
pre_min = pre_min - ten_percent;
if((!isNumeric(pre_max)) || (!isNumeric(pre_min))) {
    pre_max = pre_max_old;
    pre_min = pre_min_old;
}

yrange.set('start', pre_min);
yrange.set('end', pre_max);


// This is what I tried. When using these variables, I passed them in the CustomJS args dict, of course.
//yrange_other1.trigger('change');
//yrange_other2.trigger('change');
//xrange_other1.trigger('change');
//xrange_other2.trigger('change');
//soure_other1.trigger('change');
//soure_other2.trigger('change');
"""
```

I'm using python 2.7.10 and Bokeh version 0.12.3.

Comment: Which version of python are you working with? Also could you provide the `code` in for you callback?

Comment: I updated the question!